# if e else em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá, estou com uma dúvida sobre a ordem dos comandos. 
Meu script ficou assim:

```
if salario <= 1250:
    aumento = (salario * 15 / 100) + salario
    print('Seu salário com reajuste é R${:.2f}'.format(aumento))
else:
    aumento = (salario * 10 / 100) + salario
    print('Seu salário com reajuste é R${:.2f}'.format(aumento))
```

Caso eu altere a ordem do calculo para

```
if salario <= 1250:
    aumento = (salario * 10 / 100) + salario
    print('Seu salário com reajuste é R${:.2f}'.format(aumento))
else:
    aumento = (salario * 15 / 100) + salario
    print('Seu salário com reajuste é R${:.2f}'.format(aumento))
```

Ele me retorna o valor errado. Alguém sabe me dizer se existe alguma ordem de declaração

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
if salario <= 1250:
    aumento = (salario * 15 / 100) + salario #reajusta em 15%
else:
    aumento = (salario * 10 / 100) + salario #reajusta em 10%

print('Seu salário com reajuste é R${:.2f}'.format(aumento))
```

No seu primeiro if vc diz: se o salário for menor ou igual a 1250, dê um aumento de 15%, se for maior, aumente para 10%. No seu segundo if vc diz: se o salário for menor ou igual a 1250, dê um aumento de 10%, se for maior, aumente para 15%. Se trocou os cálculos, deve trocar a condição tb. 
O segundo seria:

```py
if salario > 1250: 
    aumento = (salario * 10 / 100) + salario 
else: 
    aumento = (salario * 15 / 100) + salario 
print('Seu salário com reajuste é R${:.2f}'.format(aumento))
```

Answer (score 2):

O `if/else` é uma estrutura de seleção condicional utilizada para desviar o fluxo de processamento entre blocos de comandos.

Seu algorítimo é:

```
Se (condição) Então
    (bloco de código Se)
Senão
    (bloco de código Senão)
Fim Se
```

Onde `condição` é uma expressão lógica cujo resultado poderá ser ou `Verdadeiro` ou `Falso`, e esse resultado decidirá qual dos `blocos de código` será executado. Segue a representação visual da estrutura de seleção condicional `if/else` em um diagrama de fluxo:

[image: Fluxograma if/else]

Aplicando esse conhecimento em seu código podemos o comentar para facilitar sua interpretação para leitores humanos:

```
#Verifica se salario é menor ou igual a 1250
if salario <= 1250:
    #Se for menor ou igual a 1250... 
    aumento = (salario * 15 / 100) + salario #reajusta em 15%
    print('Seu salário com reajuste é R${:.2f}'.format(aumento)) #Imprime salário reajustado
else:
    #Se for maior que 1250... 
    aumento = (salario * 10 / 100) + salario #reajusta em 10%
    print('Seu salário com reajuste é R${:.2f}'.format(aumento)) #Imprime salário reajustado
```

Ao entender como que cada parte parte do código funciona é possível verificar falhas ou redundâncias no código. Podemos ver que a linha onde imprime o salário é exatamente a mesma em ambos os blocos:

```
print('Seu salário com reajuste é R${:.2f}'.format(aumento)) #Imprime salário
```

Nesse caso podemos melhorar o código aplicando um princípio de programação chamado [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/137387) ou *Não repita a si mesmo* cujo a filosofia é de remover as redundâncias de código

```
#Verifica se salario é menor ou igual a 1250
if salario <= 1250:
    #Se for menor ou igual a 1250... 
    aumento = (salario * 15 / 100) + salario #reajusta em 15%
else:
    #Se for maior que 1250... 
    aumento = (salario * 10 / 100) + salario #reajusta em 10%

#Imprime salário com reajuste independentemente de qual seja
print('Seu salário com reajuste é R${:.2f}'.format(aumento))
```

Answer (score 1):

Na estrutura if else apenas um dos blocos e executado, no caso se a primeira condição for verdadeira(if) então sera executado o bloco if. O bloco else só sera executado caso a primeira condição seja falsa. No exemplo, pra ter o mesmo resultado que a primeira você deve mudar a condição para **if(salario > 1250)**. Assim o aumento sera de 15% para salario de de ate 1250 e 10% para salários maiores. Senão nos dois exemplos se o salario for exatamente 1250 o primeiro bloco sera executado (if).